# fading tikz fancyhdr problem in book printing

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, book-design, printing

I recently had a book printed, where I used fading lines in the header. In the PDF it looks correct, bu in the actual print, the lines on the left pages didn't fade as much as the lines on the right pages, so the lines seems "cut" (apologies for blurred pictures):

[image: incomplete fadings in printed version]
<sub>(source: [itlars.no](http://itlars.no/tex/fadings.jpg))</sub>

The code is, I think, identical, so I can't understand why..? This is how it looks in the PDF:

[image: correct fadings in pdf]
<sub>(source: [itlars.no](http://itlars.no/tex/fadings_pdf.jpg))</sub>

And an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openany]{book}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm, left=3cm, bottom=2cm, top=2.5cm, headsep=1.1cm, paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=27cm, layoutwidth=19cm, layoutheight=26cm, layouthoffset=0.5cm, layoutvoffset=0.5cm, showcrop, asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

% Headers
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.6}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{} % Remove head fields
\fancyfoot{} % Remove foot fields

\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize\textcolor{gray}\leftmark\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\bfseries\normalsize\textcolor{darkgray}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgray}\thepage\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize\textcolor{gray}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip4pt
\ifodd\count0\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[darkgray,path fading=west] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,0.02);
\end{tikzpicture}\else\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[darkgray,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,0.02);
\end{tikzpicture}\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Best Regards
Lars

Comment: It looked fine when I printed it.  Maybe the problem is in your printer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that it's the actual book print that is the problem. Regular prints from the PDF are fine.

Comment: Old versions of Postscript interpreter can't render fadings... Your printer probably uses an old PDF / Postscript interpreter.